# How to retrieve images from mysql and store in folder using python?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have a table in `mysql` which has images with user_id. I want to retrieve the images with user ids and store them in a folder with `user_id` appended to the image.

Example: user_id = 22334, image: pp.jpg
then the output would be `'22334_timestamp_pp.jpg'`.

I have the following code which retrieves the image but I am unable to store it in the desired format:

```
import pymysql
import io 
import PIL.Image
import cv2
import os
db = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'root', '123456', 'staging_db')  
cursor = db.cursor()  

query = """select user_id, images_pic from user_data limit 5;"""        
data = cursor.execute(query)  
r = cursor.fetchone()
uimg = io.BytesIO(r[1])
img = PIL.Image.open(uimg)
img = cv2.imread('PIL.Image.open(uimg)', 0)
path = '/home/devlappy/Desktop/model'
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path , 'user.jpg'), img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
db.close()
```

Comment: Could You pleas be more specific? What are You having trouble with? Saving the file to disk? setting the desired name for the file?

Comment: both actually. saving to the disk is the main problem. I can do away with the name.

Comment: Are You getting any kind of error? add some try/except in the image manipulation streps: `try: img = cv2.imread('PIL.Image.open(uimg)', 0) except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))`, ....

Comment: Yes this code gives an error. Can I just simply save the image as img.save()?